# loading con ajax en codeigniter mientras se ejecuta job SQL Server

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Les cuento, llevo ya un tiempo desarrollando una plataforma en PHP con codeigniter en su versión 3.0, estoy conectado a una base de datos local SQL Server, en la cual tengo un job llamado Automático. Este job es ejecutado mediante la función del modelo "ejecutar_job":

CONTROLADOR

```
public function ejecutar() // Enfocado a UCF - Consolidar BBDD
{
    $this->load->model('modelo');
    $this->modelo->ejecutar_job();
}
```

MODELO

```
 function ejecutar_job()
    {
            try
            {       
                    $query = $this->db->simple_query("EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Automatico';");
                    return 1;
            }

            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                    echo $e;
                    return 0;
            }


    }
```

hasta ahí todo bien, pero como es un job que tarda más menos 2 min. necesito una forma de que la plataforma distinga cuando ha terminado su proceso. Para ello pensé en AJAX, implementando el siguiente código:

AJAX en VISTA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(event)
    {
        var url="<?php echo base_url("index.php/welcome/ejecutar");?>";
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,

        beforeSend: function(){
                $('#cargando').html("<img src='<?php echo base_url('imagenes/cargando.gif');?>'>");
            },
        })

        .done(function(data) {
        alert('Envío Satisfactorio!');
                location.href = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/descargar_consolidado');?>";

    })
    })
</script>
```

Este código debería poner una imagen.gif mientras se ejecuta la acción y cuando esta halla terminado, saltaría a la función de ".done" redireccionando hacia la página de descarga del archivo.

El problema es: la ejecución del job si se realiza, y también redirecciona hacia la página de descargas, pero no puedo lograr que se mantenga la imagen "cargando" todo el tiempo de ejecución. Más bien apenas intento accionar el AJAX salta hacia '.done' sin que halla terminado el tiempo de ejecución, lo que provoca que el documento de descarga no esté listo.

Puede que sea un error o problema muy simple, pero no logro resolverlo. Si me hechan una ayuda sería genial...

Saludos!

Comment: Devuelves algo? En tu peticion ajax?

Comment: No, no devuelvo nada. El proceso consolida unas tablas excel y csv. Pero no tiene ningun retorno.

Comment: hay alguna forma de capturar aquel periodo en que se está ejecutando el job?

Comment: alguien ? ... no he podido arreglarlo aún

Comment: has revisado que tu jobs funcione correctamente?, y en el controlador verifica si se completo lo que tienes en tu modelo e intenta devolver algo.. esto para probar que todo este funcionando como debe en tu código php

Comment: Si, mi job funciona correctamente. Al revisar el historial del job, este si se ejecuta. Intenté retornando el valor "1" del try-catch, lo captura de inmediato y no espera el término de la ejecución. De seguro es algo muy simple, pero realmente estoy muy estancado en aquello

Comment: public function ejecutar() // Controlador utilizado para retornar elemento. 
{ 

$post=$this->input->post(); 
$this->load->model('modelo'); 
$data=$this->modelo->ejecutar_job(); 
echo $data; 
return $data;
}

Comment: @Criss tienes alguna idea de como realizarlo?

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, descubrí que cuando se trabaja con JOBS en SQL Server, como no tienes ningún tipo de retorno del JOB (a menos que lo parametrices), no puede esperar a que se realice... finalmente hice una consulta para determinar si el job termina, y otra para conocer su status final. Cuando llamo al JOB, llamo a estas consultas y todo resuelto... si alguien tiene el mismo problema, mi solución fue:

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado, descubrí que cuando se trabaja con JOBS en SQL Server, como no tienes ningún tipo de retorno del JOB (a menos que lo parametrices), no puede esperar a que se realice... finalmente hice una consulta para determinar si el job termina, y otra para conocer su status final. Cuando llamo al JOB, llamo a estas consultas y todo resuelto (Desconocía que existían ciertas tablas que controlaban las acciones de los jobs)... si alguien tiene el mismo problema, mi solución fue:

CONTROLADOR :

```
public function ejecutar() // Consolidado de documentos del servicio 
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('username')){
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('modelo');
            $valor=$this->modelo->ejecutar_job();
            $aux_termino['valor'] = 5;
            $aux_status['valor'] = 10;
            while($aux_termino['valor'] == 5){                          //5 = no ha terminado, 1 = ha terminado
                $termino=$this->modelo->comprobar_termino_job1();
                $aux_termino=json_decode(json_encode($termino),true);   //pasar desde objecto json a array[]
                sleep(4);                                               //para no saturar el servidor
            }
            $status=$this->modelo->comprobar_termino_status_job1();
            $aux_status = json_decode(json_encode($status),true);
            if($aux_status['valor'] == 1  || $aux_status['valor'] == '1'  ){
                redirect('welcome/descargar_consolidado');
            }
            else{
                redirect('welcome/error_ejecucion');
            }
        }
        else{
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

MODELO

```
 function ejecutar_job() // CONSOLIDACIÓN DE BASES DE DATOS DEL SERVICIO
        { 
            $t = 2;
                try
                {       
                        $query = $this->db->simple_query("EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Automatico';");
                        sleep($t);
                        return 1;
                }

                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                        echo $e;
                        return 0;
                }


        }


  function comprobar_termino_job1(){
        $consulta= "SELECT valor = 
                    CASE when 
                    (select
                    tabla1.last_executed_step_id  
                    from  msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity tabla1 
                    left outer join 
                    msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view tabla2 
                    on 
                    tabla1.job_id = tabla2.job_id 
                    where 
                    tabla2.name = 'Automatico'
                    and tabla1.start_execution_date = 
                        (select MAX(tabla1.start_execution_date) 
                        from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity tabla1 
                        left outer join 
                        msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view tabla2 
                        on
                        tabla1.job_id = tabla2.job_id 
                        where tabla2.name='Automatico')) is null 
                        then 5 else 1
                        end ";
                    $query = $this->db->query($consulta);
                    return $query->row();
}

function comprobar_termino_status_job1(){
    $consulta="SELECT run_status as valor
                from 
                msdb..sysjobhistory tabla_historial 
                inner join 
                msdb..sysjobs tabla_jobs 
                on 
                tabla_historial.job_id = tabla_jobs.job_id 
                where tabla_jobs.name='Automatico' 
                and 
                tabla_historial.instance_id = 
                (select max(instance_id) from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory 
                where step_name='Automatico')";
                $query = $this->db->query($consulta);
                return $query->row();
}
```

y la vista:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
            <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>
                        <center>Subida exitosa <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></center>
                    </h1>
                    <center><p>
                        La carga de archivos ha sido exitosa, para continuar presione el botón <i>"Consolidar"</i>
                            <br><br>
                            <!--<form action="<?php //echo base_url("index.php/welcome/ejecutar"); ?>" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" id="" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Consolidar">
                            </form>-->
                        <form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/ejecutar'); ?>" method="post" id="formulario">
                            <input type="submit" value="Consolidar" class="btn btn-danger">
                        </form>
                            <div id="cargando" class="cargando">
                            </div>              
                    </p>
                    </center>
            </div>
        </div>
<br>
</div>
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#formulario").submit(function(event){
            document.getElementById('formulario').style.display='none'; 
            $('#cargando').html("<img src='<?php echo base_url('imagenes/cargando.gif');?>'>");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```